# CheckBox dentro de um DBGrid

Tags: delphi-10

Tenho uma `DBGrid` no meu projeto e preciso que ela tenha duas Colunas com `CheckBox`.
Esse projeto é feiro em `VCL Form` e utilizo banco de Dados Firebird 2.5 que não tem campos `Boolean`. Para a verificação dos campos eu pretendia fazer algo assim:

```
if (Column.Field.Value <> '') or (Column.Field.Value = Null) then
   CheckBox.Checked := True;
```

Alguém conhece algum modo de fazer isso sem utilizar componentes de Terceiros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, criei um ClientDataSet com 2 campos, um string chamando nome e outro integer chamado selecao.

Adicionando alguns registros no formcreate

```
 ClientDataSet1.Open;
 ClientDataSet1.Append;
 ClientDataSet1Nome.AsString := 'Stack';
 ClientDataSet1Selecao.AsString := '1';
 ClientDataSet1.Append;
 ClientDataSet1Nome.AsString := 'OverFlow';
 ClientDataSet1Selecao.AsString := '0';
 ClientDataSet1.Post;
```

No evento DrawColumnCell do grid coloque o seguinte código:

```
var
  Check: Integer;
  R: TRect;
begin
  inherited;

  if ((Sender as TDBGrid).DataSource.Dataset.IsEmpty) then
    Exit;

  if(UpperCase(Column.FieldName) = 'SELECAO') then
  begin
    TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    if (TDBGrid(Sender).DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('selecao').AsInteger = 1) then
      Check := DFCS_CHECKED
    else
      Check := 0;
    R := Rect;
    InflateRect(R, -2, -2);
    DrawFrameControl(TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Handle, R, DFC_BUTTON,
      DFCS_BUTTONCHECK or Check);
  end;
end;
```

No ColEnter do Grid

```
if UpperCase(TDBGrid(Sender).SelectedField.FieldName) = 'SELECAO' then
  TDBGrid(Sender).Options := TDBGrid(Sender).Options - [dgEditing]
else
  TDBGrid(Sender).Options := TDBGrid(Sender).Options + [dgEditing];
```

No CellClick do grid

```
 if(UpperCase(Column.FieldName) = 'SELECAO') then
 begin
   ClientDataSet1.Edit;
   if(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('Selecao').AsInteger = 1) then
   begin
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('Selecao').AsInteger := 0;
   end
   else
   begin
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('selecao').AsInteger := 1;
   end;
   ClientDataSet1.Post;
   ShowMessage(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('selecao').AsString);
 end;
```

No evento GetText do field que será o check (Selecao) do ClientDataSet

```
 Text := EmptyStr;
```

Comment: Depois que testei percebi que só preciso do evento `DrawColumnCell` pois não vou precisar mudar a imagem no Clique. Muito obrigado pela Ajuda.

Comment: Você sabe fazer para marcar os itens desejados só com o mouse?